# Tracking I/O Operations

Tags: windows-7, windows, io, performance-monitor

On a Windows PC (specifically Windows 7, in this case), is there a method or tool that can be used to track / monitor the I/O operations being performed on the machine? Perhaps something similar to the Task Manager, where by you are presented with a graph that shows CPU usage over time.

**EDIT:** To clarify; by "I/O Operations" I mean operations such as copying a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) is awesome and a must-have toolset for any geek.

There is also [IOMeter](http://www.iometer.org), which is useful for benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) is a much more powerful version of the performance monitor. It shows more details on I/O, specifically the hard drives and video. I doubt it can process other I/O such as mouse and keyboard